# Is it necessary to add %Q in the shell command?

Tags: vagrant

I saw a Vagrant config just now like it:

```
host.vm.provision :shell, inline: %Q|sudo sh -c 'echo "Defaults env_keep +=\"ETCD_ENDPOINTS\"" >>/etc/sudoers'|
```

Here what's meaning about `%Q`? If not use it, can't works well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%Q|...|` is a way of *quoting* the shell command (enclosing its definition), in the context of *defining* it in a Vagrant configuration file; it is not part of the shell command itself.

Vagrant is written in Ruby, and Ruby's `%Q`-prefixed quoting mechanism is a convenient way to enclose a string that has *embedded* `'` and `"` quotes (as a string containing a shell command is likely to have), without needing to worry about *escaping* these chars. in the *definition* of that string.